# How to assert existing of one key value in array of associative array in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have such result from my code that I am trying to test:

```php
$result = [
   [
      "lable" => "first", ["type" => "customer", "balance" => 1000],
   ],
   [
      "lable" => "another", ["type" => "retailer", "balance" => 1500],
   ],

]
```

so I want to test my code and assert that is there any item in my result With `balance` more than 1200.
also, I want To assert that is there any `customer` type object in the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_reduce()` for this:

```
$isAboveThreshold = array_reduce($result, function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry || $item[0]['balance'] > 1200;
}, false);
$hasCustomer = array_reduce($result, function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry || $item[0]['type'] == 'customer';
}, false);
```

Comment: so there is no native PHP-Unit function. yes?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of for a use-case as specific as this

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way to use a built-in function, You can do something like this:

```
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testResultHasBalanceGreaterThan1200()
    {
        $result = [
            [
                "label" => "first", ["type" => "customer", "balance" => 1000],
            ],
            [
                "label" => "another", ["type" => "retailer", "balance" => 1500],
            ],
        ];

        $hasBalanceGreaterThan1200 = false;

        foreach ($result as $item) {
            if (isset($item[1]['balance']) && $item[1]['balance'] > 1200) {
                $hasBalanceGreaterThan1200 = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        $this->assertTrue($hasBalanceGreaterThan1200);
    }

    public function testResultHasCustomerTypeObject()
    {
        $result = [
            [
                "label" => "first", ["type" => "customer", "balance" => 1000],
            ],
            [
                "label" => "another", ["type" => "retailer", "balance" => 1500],
            ],
        ];

        $hasCustomerTypeObject = false;

        foreach ($result as $item) {
            if (isset($item[1]['type']) && $item[1]['type'] === 'customer') {
                $hasCustomerTypeObject = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        $this->assertTrue($hasCustomerTypeObject);
    }
}
```